# How can I check the react-query queries before execute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

For example, I've this query to fetch a list:

```
const list = useQuery('list', fetcher);
```

But I need something like a prechecking function before react-query execute that, I mean something like this:

```
const appQueryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      checkSomethingBeforeExecute: () => {
        if (itShouldExecute) {
          return true; // start fetching
        } else {
          return false; // don't fetch and abort query
        }
      }
    },
  },
});
```

In fact, that `checkSomethingBeforeExecute` is my idea... but I'm looking for any option or trick to implement something like that.
If you remember, there is a `select` option to transform data after fetching, but I need something to determine query exec before anything start with fetcher function.

**##new update##**

I updated my question for this example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from 'react-query';

const client = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      retry: false
    }
  }
});

const fetcher = () => fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5').then(res => res.json());

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  const { data } = useQuery(['list', id], fetcher, { enabled: !!id });

  const change = (e) => {
    setId(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={change}>
        {
          Array(30).fill().map((i, ii) => <option value={ii} key={ii}>item - {ii}</option>)
        }
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<QueryClientProvider client={client}><App /></QueryClientProvider>, rootElement);
```

There is a select input to handle changing state for each `id` and react-query doesn't retrieve cache and fetches again for even same IDs...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the `enabled` option is what you are looking for? https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery#_top

Comment: @spuhgetty Not actually, suppose I used `enabled` for another features, I mean a trick or feature along side of these options...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your query is not ready to be executed, the `enabled` option is what you are looking for:

https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/dependent-queries

if you want to "not fetch" and "abort" the query (not sure what aborting means here), you can return a rejected Promise from your queryFn:

```
useQuery(key, () => {
  if (itShouldExecute) {
    return axios.get(...)
  }
  return Promise.reject(new Error("something error"))
})
```

be aware that this will put the query in an error state and potentially trigger retries. The enabled option will not run the queryFn at all and will put your query into `idle` state. I think these are the two available options.

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for a trick to handle cache for `enabled: false` or conditional queries (fetching after onClick or onChange). I was actually thinking to check cache with `queryClient.getQueryData(key)`before execute the fetcher function for which queries have `enabled: false` or `enabled: !!state`... you know, I had doubt on to use react-query, because there is no benefit if I can't cache conditional queries data 

Comment: by the way, I updated my question with a simple example, could you please check that example? cache doesn't work with that scenario...

Comment: in your example, if data is available for a given id, you will get it immediately from the cache, and you get a background refetch with the default staleTime of zero. That is expected. You can customize staleTime to a higher value if you want.